# Spring webflux session management on login

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-webflux

I'm trying to implement a classic /login webservice with spring webflux.
But globally I'm struggling to understand how it works.

Here is some code parts :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("auth")
class AuthWebservice(
    private val reactiveAuthenticationManager: ReactiveAuthenticationManager,
    private val serverSecurityContextRepository: ServerSecurityContextRepository,
) {

    @GetMapping("me")
    fun me(exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Principal> {
        return exchange.getPrincipal<Principal>()
    }

    @PostMapping("login")
    fun login(@RequestBody dto: LoginDto, exchange: ServerWebExchange): Mono<Unit> {

        return reactiveAuthenticationManager.authenticate(
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                dto.email, dto.password
            )
        ).map { authentication ->
            serverSecurityContextRepository.save(exchange, SecurityContextImpl(authentication))
                .contextWrite(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.withAuthentication(authentication))
        }
    }
}
```

And on the configuration :

```
@Bean
fun serverSecurityContextRepository() = WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository()
```

At this end, I expect to have a session id in the set-cookie.
But after reading the code of WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository I see that there will be no session created if no session exists, which looks odd to me.

What am I missing ?

Comment: What makes you think there will be no session created? I don't see that anywhere in that code. In the end all calls lead to [`ServerWebExchange.getSession`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/server/ServerWebExchange.html#getSession()) which always returns a `Session`. Either an existing one or a new one.

Comment: @M.Deinum : on spring's code we have  exchange.getSession().doOnNext((session) -> {...})
But on debugger, I don't go into the doOnNext.

Comment: It is a reactive pipeline, so in the end you will only get into it after a subscribe. Debugging reactive pipelines is a bit of a headache in my experience.

Comment: @M.Deinum : You are right, with the subscribe() it now works.
Thanks a lot, you saved me hours (I'm new using webflux).

If you want to put your comments as answer, I will upvote it.

Comment: But you shouldn't be calling subscribe yourself. Your client, in the end, should do that, so generally if you call `subscribe` yourself, there is some error in your pipeline.

Comment: @M.Deinum : Thanks for the tip. I didn't need to use subscribe() if I use flatMap() instead of map()